# Full background using :cover; adds horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, background-image, frontend

I am working on a website which needs a header with full background image & 650 height.
At the moment i am using background-size: cover; property with 100% width.

While, it's working it leaves an awkward horizontal scroll of about 50px on right side. Which is lot more prominent in smaller resolutions.

I tried applying background to body instead of header div too. But same thing happens there as well.

You can see a preview here - 
http://nitingarg.com/projects/tfe/

Answer (score 1):

It's actually the padding on your footer that is causing the scrolling. It's 100% with a padding of 40px. So that's the full page width + 40px. Remove the padding or make it "padding: 20px 0px;" and you should be good to go.

Comment: nice find +1, moreover you would like to recommend shorthands, he is using `margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0;` can be also written as `margin: 0 0 0 0;` or `margin: 0;`

Comment: You can keep the footer padding if you add "box-sizing:border-box ; -moz-box-sizing:border-box"  to it's CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your webpage source code, with zoom 100% it have horizontal scroll of about 50px on right side but when you increase the zooming horizontal will increase more & more.

try below css as i solve the same problem for my own website

```
.header {
    min-width:980px; 
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.container {
    width:100%; 
    height:650px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Good luck :)